# Collision detection / physics for simple game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection, game-physics

Hi i am currently working on a mini game for class (first time doing something like this) and i dont really know how to start with **collision detection** at all. Okay the game i'm creating is a top down sumo fighting game on a icy circular arena where you move around gaining momentum and **velocity** and try to knock each other off to gain points. So far i have the movement acceleration/friction pretty much down and I also have a system to detect when a collision occurs, i just don't know how to actually push the characters away when they collide. I think i will base the knock back amount/ damage on the **velocity** the attacker has against their velocity alongside the character's **resistance** stat that i will be adding. I also assume that I will have to do some intense math with like tangents and stuff to get the direction correct but i'm not sure how to do that at all. I would greatly appreciate any help and i am open to future help if u want to assist me on this project later via through like discord or something. Thanks for everything

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import math


#Colors
colorRed=pygame.Color(241,59,62)
colorPurple=pygame.Color(200,254,249)
colorBlue=pygame.Color(52, 207, 235)
colorGreen=pygame.Color(100,182,100)
colorWhite=pygame.Color(255,250,250)
colorBlack=pygame.Color(0,0,0)
colorOrange=pygame.Color(242,164,0)
colorBrown=pygame.Color(148,103,58)

#Dimensions
w=800
h=600
pygame.init()
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
pygame.display.set_caption ('SUMO')
centerX=w//2
centerY=h//2

#Stage
stageR=250
def stage (centerX,centerY):
    """stage (centerX,centerY) - creates a stage with given centerpoint"""
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlue, (centerX,centerY),stageR)

#Character 1
xR=int((stageR//10))
x1=int(centerX-(stageR*0.8))
y1=centerY
x1_dir=0
y1_dir=0
def char1 (x1,y1):
    """char1 (x1,y1) - creates char1 at given coordinates"""
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorRed, (x1,y1),xR)
print (x1)
print (centerX)

#Character 2
x2=int(centerX+(stageR*0.8))
y2=centerY
x2_dir=0
y2_dir=0
def char2 (x2,y2):
    """char2 (x2,y2) - creates char1 at given coordinates"""
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorGreen, (x2,y2),xR)





while True:
    screen.fill(colorBlack)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #Game Exit
        if event.type== QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    distance=math.hypot(x1-x2,y1-y2)
    if distance <= 2*xR:
        print ("HIT")

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[K_d] or keys[K_a]:
        x1_dir += 0.1 if keys[K_d] else -0.1
    else:
        x1_dir *= 0.98

    if keys[K_w] or keys[K_s]:
        y1_dir += 0.1 if keys[K_s] else -0.1
    else:
        y1_dir *= 0.98

# -------------------- CHAR2 MOVEMENT --------------------

    if keys[K_RIGHT] or keys[K_LEFT]:
        x2_dir += 0.1 if keys[K_RIGHT] else -0.1
    else:
        x2_dir *= 0.98

    if keys[K_UP] or keys[K_DOWN]:
        y2_dir += 0.1 if keys[K_DOWN] else -0.1
    else:
        y2_dir *= 0.98


    stage (centerX,centerY)
    char1 (round(x1),round(y1))
    char2 (round(x2),round(y2))
    x1+=x1_dir
    y1+=y1_dir
    x2+=x2_dir
    y2+=y2_dir
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(60)
```

Comment: `pygame.Rect()` has `colliderect()` so you can do `player.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect)`. `pygame.Sprite` has even `collidecircle`

Comment: if I'm not wrong them `(x1-x2)/(y1-y2)` or `(y1-y2)/(x1-x2)` gives `tangents(alpha)` between players so you can use this angle to get new direction after collision.

Comment: [pymunk](http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/), See also similar portal [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reflect the movement vectors (`x1_dir`, `y1_dir`) and (`x2_dir`, `y2_dir`) when the objects hit.
For a given incident vector `I` and surface normal `N`, the reflection direction calculated as `I - 2.0 * dot(N, I) * N`.

The normal vector is the [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) from one center point to the other, when the objects hit,
Detect the hit and normalize the vector between the center points (divide the vector by `distance`):

```py
nv = [x1-x2, y1-y2]
distance=math.hypot(nv[0], nv[1])
if distance <= 2*xR:
   nv = [nv[0]/distance, nv[1]/distance]
```

Use [`pygame.math.Vector2.reflect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.reflect) to calculate the reflection.
Use [`pygame.math.Vector2.length`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.scale_to_length) to compute the length of the reflected vectors and exchange there length by [`pygame.math.Vector2.scale_to_length`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.scale_to_length):

```py
nv = [x1-x2, y1-y2]
distance=math.hypot(nv[0], nv[1])
if distance <= 2*xR:
    nv = pygame.math.Vector2(nv[0], nv[1]) / distance

    rd1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1_dir, y1_dir).reflect(nv)
    rd2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2_dir, y2_dir).reflect(nv)

    len1, len2 = rd1.length(), rd2.length()
    if len1 > 0:
        rd1.scale_to_length(len2)
        x1_dir, y1_dir = rd1.x, rd1.y
    else:
        x1_dir, y1_dir = -x2_dir, -y2_dir
    if len2 > 0:
        rd2.scale_to_length(len1)
        x2_dir, y2_dir = rd2.x, rd2.y
    else:
        x2_dir, y2_dir = -x1_dir, -y1_dir
```

[image]

---

Since it is not possible to detect the "hit" exactly, when the distance between the players is `2*xR` it is necessary to correct the position of the players and to find the point when the distance is exactly `2*xR`:

```py
v12 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1-x2, y1-y2)
distance = v12.length()
hit_dist = 2*xR
if distance <= hit_dist:
    # vector beteween center points
    nv = v12.normalize()
    # movement direction and combined relative movement
    d1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1_dir, y1_dir)
    d2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2_dir, y2_dir)
    dd = d1 - d2
    if dd.length() == 0:
        # normalized movement and normal distances
        ddn = dd.normalize()
        dir_dist  = ddn.dot(v12)
        norm_dist = pygame.math.Vector2(-ddn[0], ddn[1]).dot(v12)
        # minimum distance along the line of relative movement
        min_dist = math.sqrt(hit_dist*hit_dist - norm_dist*norm_dist)
        if dir_dist < min_dist:
            # update postions of the players so that the distance is 2*xR
            d1l, d2l = d1.length(), d2.length()
            d1n = d1/d1l if d1l > 0 else d1
            d2n = d2/d2l if d2l > 0 else d2
            x1 -= d1n.x * d1l / (d1l+d2l)
            y1 -= d1n.y * d1l / (d1l+d2l)
            x2 -= d2n.x * d2l / (d1l+d2l)
            y2 -= d2n.y * d2l / (d1l+d2l)
            # recalculate vector beteween center points
            v12 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1-x2, y1-y2)
            nv = v12.normalize()

        # reflect movement vectors
        rd1 = d1.reflect(nv)
        rd2 = d2.reflect(nv)
        len1, len2 = rd1.length(), rd2.length()
        if len1 > 0:
            rd1 = rd1 * len2 / len1
            x1_dir, y1_dir = rd1.x, rd1.y
        else:
            x1_dir, y1_dir = -x2_dir, -y2_dir
        if len2 > 0:
            rd2 = rd2 * len1 / len2
            x2_dir, y2_dir = rd2.x, rd2.y
        else:
            x2_dir, y2_dir = -x1_dir, -y1_dir
```

Comment: sorry i was busy for a few days thanks for the reply im just a bit confused im not really good at this so this looks really confusing not entirely sure how this works yet and uh im assuming the last chunk of code is the one i use but im getting errors like    ddn = dd.normalize()
ValueError: Can't normalize Vector of length Zero

Comment: uhm it says that the return is outside of the function

Comment: sorry what do you mean where is the answer? i tried using what you sent me.

Comment: i used the edited one and it says "return is outside of the function"

Comment: Hey @Rabbid76 yo uhm does it work for you i just tried it both circles still phase through each other with no interaction

Comment: @Chynx Yes of course it works for me. I've created the gif with it. See my code: https://pastebin.com/C6JCVLrU

Comment: 76 i saw yours look this is what mine still does https://gyazo.com/8ef8aca23ed63950e43a6620c9f1be77
what did i do wrong ?
https://github.com/sniper2x5/Python/blob/master/ice.py

Comment: alright just fixed it the collision works now thanks. Also occasionally the balls when they collide they get stuck in each other and then wierd interactions occur is this a framerate/update issue?