# How can i make the ball bounce in the right directions

Tags: python, pygame

Im making an air hokey game using pygame ,  but i have no idea how to make the ball bounce in the right direction when the player hits it.

i tried making the ball move in the x direction if the player hits it and if the player is under the ball or aboce it  i made it move in the y and x direction but that didnt work

```
import pygame
import math
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
background = pygame.image.load("ER.png")



player1 = pygame.image.load("eee.png")
px = 20
py = 148
change = 0
cy = 0
player2 = pygame.image.load("a.png")
px2 = 700
py2 = 148
cx2 = 0
cy2 = 0

ball = pygame.image.load("qw.png")
bx = 351
by = 148
chx = 0
chy = 0

def balls(x,y):
    screen.blit(ball,(x,y))
def p1(x, y):
    screen.blit(player1,(x , y))
def p2(x, y):
    screen.blit(player2,(x , y))  
def  colid(ex,ey, bx, by):
    d = math.sqrt((math.pow(ex - bx, 2)) + (math.pow(by - ey,2)))
    if d < 40:
        return True
    else:
        return False    


run = True
while run:
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                change += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                change += -1 
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                cy += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                cy += -1 
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                cx2 -= 1
                print(px2)
                print(py2)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                cx2 += 1 
                print(px2)
                print(py2) 
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                cy2 += 1
                print(px2)
                print(py2)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                cy2 += -1
                print(px2)
                print(py2)    
      
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                change -= 1    
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                change += 1 
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    cy -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    cy += 1 
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                cx2 += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                cx2 -= 1  
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                cy2 -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                cy2 += 1 
    colide =  colid(bx, by, px, py)           



    if colide:
        print("colided")
                          
    
    bx += ch
    py2 += cy2
    px2 += cx2
    py += cy  
    px += change
    balls(bx,by)
    p1(px,py)
    p2(px2, py2)
  
    if px <=  -8:
        px = -8
    if px >=  326:
        px = 326    
    if py <=  -8:
        py = -8
    if py >= 312:
        py = 312  

    if px2 >=  712:
        px2 = 712 

    if py2 <=  -8:
        py2 = -8
    if py2 >= 312:
        py2 = 312   
    if px2 <=  378:
        px2 = 378        
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: my bad i probably missed typed that cuz i tried typing collision but then deleted it

Comment: You might find some ideas here: [Collision detection / physics for simple game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656983/collision-detection-physics-for-simple-game/59658289#59658289)

Answer (score 2):

You update the ball position with

```
    bx += ch
```

but the `colide` result does not influence `ch`.
Therefore the ball behavior does not change when Player1 hits it.
Have your `if` statement do something like this
after `print`ing that the ball collided:

```
    ch = -ch
```

This assumes values like `1` or `-1`.
The code you posted does not set `ch`.
If `ch` is zero the ball will remain stationary.

You might also make your bounds check code flip the sign,
so the ball bounces off the left and right walls
independent of what Player1 is doing.
Or try one of these special effects within the bounds check:

```
    ch *= -0.95  # friction slows the ball down

    ch *= -1.05  # hot walls continually impart more energy to the ball
```

---

You have an inconveniently large number of variables.
You could get away with roughly half as many if a `class` introduced
the concept of a `Point` located at some (x, y).
You might even create a `Ball` class that models both position and velocity.

---

A related difficulty is that you *almost* adhered to a consistent
naming scheme. Clean that up and you'll find design and debugging much easier.